# comparing data from one sheet and writing on another sheet in same workbookusing Apache POI and Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class WriteExcelSheet {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File src = new File ("C:\\Java_Selenium_Temp\\QATempData.xlsx");

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);

            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

            XSSFSheet qa = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFSheet repo = wb.getSheet("report");

            String data1 = qa.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            String data2 = qa.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

            //qa.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue("Fail");
            //qa.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue("Pass");

            if(data1 !=data2){
                System.out.println("Fata");
                repo.getRow(1).createCell(1).setCellValue("Test");
            }


            //reporx.getRow(0).createCell(1).setCellValue("FPASS");

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(src);

            wb.write(fos);

            wb.close();
            System.out.println("writing successfull ....");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception");
        }

    }

}
```

I am try to read data from one sheet, compare two column and based on the comparison write data on a different sheet.
here is my code shown above

*The error I am getting is, the first line "Fata" is the output from line 38 and error is showing up in line 39*

> Fata
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at ReadExcel.WriteExcelSheet.main(WriteExcelSheet.java:39)

any help why I am getting this or how can I do this

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create the row first.

```
repo.createRow(1).createCell(1).setCellValue("Test");
```

In addition, you may use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` method when comparing Strings. This could be a different discussion but just for your information.

```
data1.equals(data2)
```

or

```
data1.equalsIgnorCase(data2)
```